# Installing Python eggs under PyPy

Tags: python, development-environment, pypy

**How do I install Python egg under PyPy?**

During installation, PyPy created `/usr/lib64/pypy-1.5/site-packages/` directory. So, I tried using easy_install with prefix set to this directory, however it complains that this is not a valid directory for eggs. Do I just copy eggs from `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, or is it as easy as using easy_install (with some changes in configuration, perhaps)?

My working environment is Fedora 15 Beta, Python 2.7.1 (`/usr/bin/python`), PyPy 1.5.0-alpha0 with GCC 4.6.0 (in `/usr/bin/pypy`, installed from RPM using yum), easy_install version is: distribute 0.6.14 (`usr/bin/easy_install`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that you have distribute installed specifically for PyPy.  I don't know how fedora packages things, but in general installing a package for cpython does not make it available also for PyPy. In particular, /usr/bin/easy_install is probably CPython-only.

If you use a "normal" install of PyPy, you have this directory structure:

- /opt/pypy-1.5/

  - bin/
  - site-packages/
  - lib-python/
  - lib_pypy/

Then you can download http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py and execute it:

```
$ /opt/pypy-1.5/bin/pypy distribute_setup.py
```

Now, you should have /opt/pypy-1.5/bin/easy_install, which will install packages inside /opt/pypy-1.5/site-packages.

However, I have no clue how pypy is packaged in fedora.  It it's "just" installed in /usr/bin, then there are chances that installing distribute will overwrite the original cpython's /usr/bin/easy_install.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

`/usr/bin/easy_install` was in fact part of CPython.
However, I just downloaded `distribute_setup.py` and ran it with pypy. It installed easy_install into `/usr/lib64/pypy-1.5/bin` (so it didn't override any CPython-related files - probably because of different PYTHONPATH of CPython and PyPy).

Comment: the distribute_setup.py link does not work any more, this one does : http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py

Comment: Distribute is no longer maintained, it has been merged with [Setup Tools](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools)