# easy_install with pypy while Python is installed

Tags: python, setuptools, easy-install, pypy, distribute

I installed [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) while still having Python 2.7 on my system.

- How do I install and then use `easy_install` with PyPy?
- What is the syntax for distinguishing where I want to install to with `easy_install`?
- Should I set any environment variables for ease of use?

I'm on Windows, but these questions seem relevant for all platform...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install easy_install for pypy manually.

It's explained in the answer to this question : 
[Installing Python eggs under PyPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885820/installing-python-eggs-under-pypy)

Comment: If you have python's executable in your path, use `pypy [whatever]` syntax for all installations so that it will install under pypy and not python

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution is to install pip. Following the instructions in [pip's documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html):

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
pypy get-pip.py
pypy -m pip install ipython
```

Comment: Prefixing with `sudo` is generally needed.

Comment: @EOL: running pip as root is not recommended. Running with `--user` or in a virtualenv is a much less horrible idea.

Comment: This is true unless you want to install Python packages for all users, right? or is there officially a better method (beyond using a general package manager when possible)?

Answer (score 2):

At least this worked for me:

```
$ brew install pypy
$ pypy -m easy_install ipython

$ /usr/local/share/pypy/ipython
Python 2.7.3 (480845e6b1dd, Jul 31 2013, 10:58:28)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

Comment: This may work, but I haven’t seen any recommendations for using `easy_install` that weren’t written several years ago.  For the past ≈2 years, `setuptools` has been the unifying standard. (Before that was a competition between `setuptools` and `distribute`; they eventually merged into the current `setuptools`.)  I’m less familiar with pypy (and whether it needs something Pythons 2 & 3 don’t), but it’s worth double-checking this, just in case.