# add new module for pypy

Tags: python, twisted, pypy

I want to use the pypy interpreter. Currently my application works well under python 2.5 and CPython, as I view the variable `sys.path`:

```
'/ apps / work', '/ apps / work / application' Twisted-12.0.0-py2.5-linux-x86_64.egg.
```

How can I add the path to the interpreter PyPy?

Answer (score 0):

> Currently my application works well under python 2.5 and CPython

[CPython is the name of the reference python implementation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython)

`2.5` is a version of the language semantics. The language semantics have nothing to do with the implementation. `2.5` has to do with **Python the language**. It can be that another implementation (such as [pypy](http://pypy.org/), or [jython](http://www.jython.org/)) may be implementing the version 2.5 (or higher) of the `Python` language semantics.

> How can I add the path to the interpreter PyPy

CPython works with an environment variable called `PYTHONPATH` in order to find the location of modules. Pypy works the same. You can view the contents of the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable by issuing (assuming you are using a UNIX like environment) `echo $PYTHONPATH` or `printenv PYTHONPATH` .

If you do not get the output you desire (or any output for that matter) from running the above, feel free to edit your `.bashrc` file and append to it the following line:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/the/path/to/your/modules/"
```

replacing of course `/the/path/to/your/modules` with the actual path.

The above change will not take effect until you start a new shell or reload the config file by running this on the command line:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

*If you are working on a Windows environment, instructions for setting PYTHONPATH under Windows are* [here](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/setting-up-windows-python-path-system-variable.php)

**[EDIT]:** You can also see a guide for adding eggs under Pypy from a more authoritative source (Antonio Cuni is a Pypy developer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5894355/1426969)

Comment: thank you for the answer
for '/ apps / work', '/ apps / work / application', I managed to harden and but twistd (Twisted-12.0.0-py2.5-linux-x86_64.egg) I do not know how do. please an idea

Comment: Maybe the real question has nothing to do with PYTHONPATH and is: how do I install Twisted for PyPy?

Comment: @ArminRigo I don't know. I do not think I can follow the op anymore. Apart from that, if you believe my answer contains misleading information I will be happy to delete it.

Comment: @NlightNFotis: No no, your answer is fine.  I'm just trying to react to Richard's comments, which lead me to believe that your answer is not helpful for him.

Answer (score 0):

You can install software on PyPy by using PyPy to run the software's installer.  For example:

```
$ pypy setup.py install
```

You could try sharing installations between CPython and PyPy by setting `PYTHONPATH` but this is error prone (CPython and PyPy don't use exactly the same bytecode format, their native-code extension modules are not ABI compatible, etc) so unless you have very specific understanding of these issues and specific requirements for doing so, it's not really a good idea.